# Calculated Column with IF statement

Tags: 2016

so i've created a calendar with differents event and with the usage of the calculated value i've created an icon who refers to outlook. My problem is that this icon should appear only when the events is not passed. I though about the usage of the condition IF but i can't make it work. Probably with my inexperience i'm missing something or maybe is not possible. Can someone help me?
Here's the code that i use, without the statement IF

```
="<a href='()"
&"?Subject=" & [Title] & "' target='_top'>"
&"<img src='http://()' 
style='height:20px;width:20px;'/>"
&"</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

so i solved my problem with the following code:

```
=IF([End Time]>=[Calculated Column],"<a href=""mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"
&"?Subject="&Title&""" target=_top>"
&"<img src=https://mysite/SiteAssets/thFC8C6PTP.jpg style=height:20px;width:20px;/>"
&"</a>","EVENTO PASSATO")
```

But i would like also to add a Body to the email, can someone help me?

Comment: You can add a new parameter to your href attribute:`&body=`, but only `text/plain` content is allowed.

Comment: So i added &Body= but the field in the email is empty, missing someting?"             <a href=""mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"
&"?Subject="&Title&""" target=_top &Body=Here goes the text>"

Comment: Try using:

`=IF([End Time] >= [Calculated Column], "<a href='mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com?subject=Email-Title&body=Email-Body' target='_top'>"
&"<img src='https://mysite/SiteAssets/thFC8C6PTP.jpg' style='height:20px;width:20px'/>"
&"</a>","EVENTO PASSATO")`

Comment: The Point is that the Subject of the email should be "dinamic" and take the title of the Column. I tried many ways to code but there's no way to have the CC or the Body